# linux kernel Makefile name="People's Front"

Tags: linux, kernel, make

Does anybody know the meaning of the string "People's Front" in the linux kernel source Makefile name?

```
> uname -a

Linux debian 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Just installed the kernel source from the debian official repository

```
 > sudo apt-get install linux-source
```

the referred line:

```
> cat /usr/src/linux-source-4.19/Makefile | grep "NAME"
NAME = "People's Front"
```

Comment: *Which* kernel source? *Which* linux version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Linux kernel versions since 1.2 have included a `NAME=` field in their Makefile.

Wikipedia has a list of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_kernel_names

Note that the string `"People's Front"` is in double quotes, both the previous and the next names in the series, `Merciless Moray` and `Shy Crocodile` respectively, aren't. This is exactly how they are in the actual kernel source: you can verify that for yourself in https://git.kernel.org.

Here's the update that labelled the 4.20-rc4 release candidate and, at the same time, changed the `NAME=` to `Shy Crocodile`:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/Makefile?id=2e6e902d185027f8e3cb8b7305238f7e35d6a436

I think it's nothing more than Linus's long-running private joke, or something along those lines.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks.